# Is there a way you can change click data with another function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, a while back, I had taken an on/off switch click function off of here. Now, I need to add a function that changes the data coming from that function onclick of another function. I tried a few basic things; tried adding 1 to the variable, changing the *this* data, etc. I've been working on this for days, yet I haven't found a single solution. Maybe there's an issue with my code that I missed?

I thought I could change the variable, but that didn't work.

```css
#doc {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    z-index: 3;
    color: #0088ff;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 100px;
    top: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#docWindow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 250px;
    height: 295px;
    background-color: #272727;
    top: 65px;
    left: 78px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1F1F1F;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 250px;
    height: 5px;
    top:0px;
    background-color: #0088ff;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#html {
    position: relative;
    color:#0088ff;
    font-size: 10;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 50px;
    top: 100px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#acc {
position: absolute;
color: #0088ff;
outline: none;
border: none;
background: transparent;
font-size: 20px;
z-index: 3;
left: 330px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: 'Verdana';
top: 22px;
}

#accWindow {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 250px;
height: 190px;
background-color: #272727;
top: 65px;
left: 265px;
border: 1px solid #1F1F1F;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
display: block;
}

#bar2 {
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
width: 250px;
height: 5px;
top:0px;
background-color: #0088ff;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#change {
position: relative;
color:#0088ff;
font-size: 11;
z-index: 3;
font-family: 'Verdana';
user-select: none;
font-weight: bold;
top: 25px;
left: 45px;
outline: none;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: transparent;
}

#change2 {
position: relative;
color:#0088ff;
font-size: 10;
z-index: 3;
font-family: 'Verdana';
user-select: none;
font-weight: bold;
top: 65px;
left: 45px;
outline: none;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: transparent;
}

#out {
position: relative;
color:#0088ff;
font-size: 10;
z-index: 3;
font-family: 'Verdana';
user-select: none;
font-weight: bold;
top: 125px;
left: -75px;
outline: none;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: transparent;
}
#css {
    position: relative;
    color:#0088ff;
    font-size: 10;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 50px;
    top: 150px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#ICON2 {
position: absolute;
font-family: 'Verdana';
z-index: 3;
color: #0088ff;
font-size: 20px;
outline: none;
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
left: 100px;
top: 2px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}

#java {
    position: relative;
    color:#0088ff;
    font-size: 10;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 50px;
    top: 201px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#jquery {
    position: relative;
    color:#0088ff;
    font-size: 10;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 50px;
    top: 253px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#lua {
    position: relative;
    color:#0088ff;
    font-size: 10;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 50px;
    top: 305px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#ICON1 {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    z-index: 3;
    color: #0088ff;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 180px;
    top: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.FLIP1 {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.FLIP2 {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

a {
   color: #0088ff;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
   color: #0056A3;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b3dcbaf5bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id = "documentation">
                <button id = "doc">Documentation<div id = "ICON1"><i class = "fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></div></button>
                <div id = "docWindow" style="display:none;"><div id = "bar"></div>
                    <button id = "html"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/DocOverview/HTMLDoc/htmlDocumentation.html">HTML Docs</a></button>
                    <button id = "css"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/DocOverview/CSSDoc/CSSdocumentation.html">CSS Docs</a></button>
                    <button id = "java"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/DocOverview/JSDoc/javascriptdocumentation.html">Java Docs</a></button>
                    <button id = "jquery"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/DocOverview/JQUDoc/jquerydocumentation.html">Jquery Docs</a></button>
                    <button id = "lua"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/DocOverview/LUADoc/luadocumentation.html">Lua Docs</a></button>
                </div>
                <script>   
                    var clicks1 = undefined;

                    $('#doc').click(function() {
                        clicks1 = $(this).data('clicks');
                        if (!clicks1) {
                            $("#ICON1").toggleClass("FLIP1");
                            $('#docWindow').show();
                        } else {
                            $('#docWindow').css('display', 'none');
                            $("#ICON1").toggleClass("FLIP1");
                        }
                        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks1);
                        $('#accWindow').hide();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
<div id = "account">
            <button id = "acc">Account<div id = "ICON2"><i class = "fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></div></button>
                <div id = "accWindow" style="display:none;"><div id = "bar2"></div>
                    <button id = "change"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/ACC/changeAcc/settings.html">Change Settings</a></button>
                    <button id = "change2"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/ACC/changeAcc/acc.html">Change Account</a></button>
                    <button id = "out"><a href = "/Users/1001891/Desktop/webVar/Content/ACC/changeAcc/out.html">Log Out</a></button>
                </div>
                    <script>          
                        var display = $("#docWindow").is(':visible');

                        setInterval(function(){
                            display = $("#docWindow").is(':visible');
                            $(function() {
                                if (display === true) {
                                    display = 1;
                                    console.log(display);
                                };

                                if (display === false) {
                                    display = 2;
                                    console.log(display);
                                };
                            });
                        }, 10);

                        $('#acc').click(function() {
                            if(display == 1) {
                                $('#docWindow').css('display', 'none');
                                $("#ICON1").toggleClass("FLIP1");
                                clicks1 = clicks1+1;
                            };
                    
                            var clicks2 = $(this).data('clicks');
                            if (!clicks2) {
                                $('#accWindow').show();
                                $("#ICON2").toggleClass("FLIP1");
                            } else {
                                $('#accWindow').hide();
                                $("#ICON2").toggleClass("FLIP1");
                            };
                            $(this).data("clicks", !clicks2);
                        });
                    </script>  
        </div>
```

Comment: Please explain more that what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @jerry I want to be able to reset the click data onclick of the "acc" div, so that it doesn't need to be clicked twice to open once closed by the click of the "acc" div.